# Partition not shown correctly in Ubuntu 14.04.02 LTS installer + wifi network not shown

Tags: wireless, dual-boot, partitioning

I'm trying to install Ubuntu to dual boot with Windows 7. I am on a laptop with a single hard disk in which I prepared a partition to install Ubuntu.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKzU3.jpg) is what I see on Windows partition manager, the 45GB not allocated are for Ubuntu. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIhg6.jpg)  is what I see, instead, on GParted through the live Ubuntu session, which is the same list that the installer shows when choosing "Other options" in the wizard.

Am I doing something wrong? Shouldn't I see the free 45GBs partition?

PLUS both the Ubuntu live session and the installer sees correctly my wifi card and all of the networks that are normally picked up in my flat, all of them but mine. I've tried to insert manually the wifi network but it doesn't connect to it.

EDIT: Sorry about the ubuntu screenshot being a smartphone photo, but for some reasons the live session won't let me save any file. I get the file in Windows but when I try to open them I get an error.

Comment: Are you using Dynamic Partitions in Windows?  That'll need to be turned off.

Comment: .. I see that's probably that. I'm going to format the whole drive and start off with a clean, basic disc. Time to rethink about choices.

Answer (score 2):

If you are running Windows try creating an 'ext4' partition on the unallocated space. I was facing similar problem with Windows 8 but creating a partition beforehand solved the problem. Personally i use [Minitools Partition Manager](http://www.partitionwizard.com/free-partition-manager.html) as the windows partition manager does not allow creating a ext4 partition.

Comment: My hard disk is listed as "dynamic" rather than "basic", does it change anything?

Comment: Refer to [this](http://superuser.com/questions/335872/installing-ubuntu-on-a-dynamic-disk) and [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/482768/changing-windows-dynamic-disk-partition-to-basic-partition-and-not-the-full-driv) in that case. You would have to convert your disk from dynamic to basic to install ubuntu which will involve formatting your disk. Or you can use VirtualBox.

Comment: Thank you, I'll format the whole drive and start off anew. At least now I know why I failed all those install guides.