# Install ubuntu alongside windows 10 with 4 partitions already present

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, windows-10

I am currently having windows 10 and I want to dual boot and install ubuntu 15.04 alongside my windows 10. I made a bootable usb for ubuntu,however when I was trying to install it,I saw instead of showing 'install alongside windows' it was showing 'install inside windows'.Then through a bit of searching over internet I found that it shows such type of options when you have 4 partitions already.So next time I clicked 'something else' in the installation dialog box and it showed something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gZgR.jpg).Now being a newbie I am totally struck how to tackle this problem so please help.

Here is a link that shows : 
[my partitions in windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bELFr.jpg) ,[how to adjust so that I dont loose data]

And one more thing I dont know why but it is showing windows 8 in the ubuntu installation dialog box while I have windows 10 installed in my pc

Answer (score 1):

Backup first, things can go very wrong when changing partitions.  Then it looks like you have "dynamic" partitions, instead of "basic", which is a problem -- those "dynamic" partitions need to be converted to basic first.  Then it looks like you have enough free space in the "G:" partition (59G) for a root and swap.  "G:" is 100% free, so looks like it may be deleted, then the Ubuntu installer can make the partitions needed in the free space (or do it yourself in "something else").

It isn't clear to me if this is a UEFI machine, or what disk partitioning (gpt or msdos) is used.  If msdos is used, then you will need an extended partition to hold the new logical partitions you create.  If gpt, then you can just make the new partitions.

Comment: Yeah I want to install ubuntu in G: partion only

Comment: disk partitioning style:MBR

Comment: It shows dynamic partitions which is Windows proprietary and not compatible with Linux nor with some Windows tools. Microsoft's official policy is a full backup, erase dynamic partitions and create new basic partitions. There is no undo. And whatever you do, you do need good backups. Is sdb a drive you could install Ubuntu into? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365449%28v=vs.85%29.aspx and:http://askubuntu.com/questions/482768/changing-windows-dynamic-disk-partition-to-basic-partition-and-not-the-full-driv

Answer (score 0):

You can create extended partitions, that can have multiple partitions within them.

Choose "try ubuntu" from your USB, and open Gparted application from ubuntu. From there you can create an extended partition.

It should look at little like this when you are done:
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGh22.png)

Comment: Do I need to backup data before creating extended partition

Comment: You should always backup your data. Do you know why you would have three ntfs-partitions?

Comment: I would just delete the SDA3-partition and create an extended partition. Then create two partitions in that extended partition. A swap partition of 1024 Mib and an ext4 of the rest.