# Unallocated space not recognized

Tags: system-installation, windows

Trying to install Linux alongside a long-standing Windows installation: Unallocated space not recognized by the installer

not even  by gparted

Comment: May be because of Dynamic Disks, check this once http://askubuntu.com/a/737165/497359