# GRUB failed to install after GRUB Rescue

Tags: grub2, boot-repair

I created a new partition on Windows from unallocated space (I already had 4 primary partitions, so it seems it created a dynamic partition), then when I reboot I enter in the GRUB Rescue.

I used `instmod` and then I could boot to Ubuntu.

I tried to install GRUB with boot-repair and from command line

**Using boot repair**

First I get the error

```
SFS detected. You may want to retry after converting Windows dynamic partitioning (SFS partitions) to a basic disk
```

Then I just continued with boot repair and

```
GRUB failed to install to the following devices:

/dev/sda
```

**Command line**

```
sudo update-grub
sudo grub-install dev/sda
```

I get the same *GRUB failed to install* as I mentioned above

**Using bootable usb**

I tried *boot repair* and I get the same errors as when using it on PC.

Windows is not booting, when trying I get:

```
error: device format "lad/a1eb ... /volume1" invalid must be (f|h)dN with 0<=N<128
```

My HD:

[image]

Comment: SFS is Windows proprietary dynamic partitioning which does not work with Linux. Do not create partitions with Windows if you have used all 4 primary partitions. Best to just undo, but Microsoft makes it easy to create dynamic but has no undo. Some third party tools may work, but good backups required. http://askubuntu.com/questions/482768/changing-windows-dynamic-disk-partition-to-basic-partition-and-not-the-full-driv and:https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2325331&p=13492758&viewfull=1#post13492758 There is a new ldmtool that may let you see partitions.

Comment: Just to add, before it everything: Windows and 2 Ubuntus were working fine. After I allocated one partition, everything started.

Comment: Mistake was adding partition using Windows, not gparted. But if you had made a new logical it would have been ok. Windows tools for Windows & Linux tools for Linux.

Comment: @oldfred I couldn't add a partition with gparted because it said I already had 4, then I tried with windows... and my objective was to use this partition with windows, not ubuntu.

Comment: @oldfred do you think if I unallocate all sda4 (see figure) it will boot normally? I have backup and I think it is easier to unallocate and install windows than undoing dynamic disk.

Comment: As long as you have dynamic, you will have problems. And Microsoft did not make it easy to undo. Microsofts offical policy is to fully backup, delete everything and then restore data. Major work. But you should have backup any. Try the third party software.

Comment: @oldfred thank you for help, I formated the disk. Fortunatelly I had everything on the cloud.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did: I formated the disk and installed everything again. As I had backup of windows partition, it was just time loss.