# Unable to get into windows10 after installing ubuntu 16.04LTS

Tags: dual-boot, 16.04, grub2, windows-10

I am new to Ubuntu. After installing Ubuntu 16.04 I got the grub menu and was not able to get into the windows 10. Following answers here on Ask Ubuntu, I changed the windows10 menu entry of windows 10 to `insmod part_msdos` from `insmod ldm` and now I am able to get into windows10, but it asks me to reset the PC. I ran Boot repair before and I was then unable to get the grub menu and so I installed Ubuntu from DVD. Now i am afraid of running boot repair again and hence I chose the second option of boot repair and I got the following Link http://paste2.org/IntK1g8I.

Here is an excerpt from the linked report:

```
    Create Paste
    Followup Paste
    QR

 Boot Info Script cfd9efe + Boot-Repair extra info      [Boot-Info 26Apr2016]


============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

 => Grub2 (v2.00) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 
    1915855042 of the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this 
    location and looks for (,msdos8)/grub. It also embeds following components:

    modules
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    fshelp ext2 part_msdos biosdisk
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       Extended Partition
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sda5: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       swap
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sda6: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
    Boot files:        /etc/fstab

sda7: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda8: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /grub/grub.cfg /grub/i386-pc/core.img

sda9: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda10: _________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda11: _________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /bootmgr /Boot/BCD

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /bootmgr /BOOT/BCD /Windows/System32/winload.exe

sda4: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 7/2008: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

============================ Drive/Partition Info: =============================

Drive: sda _____________________________________________________________________
Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sda1       1,612,951,550 1,953,523,711   340,572,162   5 Extended
/dev/sda5       1,612,951,552 1,622,714,367     9,762,816  82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda6       1,622,716,416 1,769,199,615   146,483,200  83 Linux
/dev/sda7       1,769,201,664 1,915,684,863   146,483,200  83 Linux
/dev/sda8       1,915,686,912 1,916,661,759       974,848  83 Linux
/dev/sda9       1,916,663,808 1,926,426,623     9,762,816  83 Linux
/dev/sda10      1,926,428,672 1,936,191,487     9,762,816  83 Linux
/dev/sda11      1,936,193,536 1,953,523,711    17,330,176  83 Linux
/dev/sda2    *          2,048       206,847       204,800  42 SFS
/dev/sda3             206,848   245,762,047   245,555,200  42 SFS
/dev/sda4         245,762,048 1,612,949,547 1,367,187,500   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS


"blkid" output: ________________________________________________________________

Device           UUID                                   TYPE       LABEL

/dev/sda10       f7344d8a-17ba-44d3-9097-953a94240200   ext4       
/dev/sda11       0f19fef8-8eed-45a5-a3cb-9ea35e0f521a   ext4       
/dev/sda2        50604E8A604E76AE                       ntfs       
/dev/sda3        B60055A300556AFF                       ntfs       
/dev/sda4        F866A8DB66A89BBE                       ntfs       
/dev/sda5        9e32046a-a1d8-43ef-b0ce-5b0467d4faf5   swap       
/dev/sda6        952ca2bf-51fd-47ff-bcd2-f8dc05ea9979   ext4       
/dev/sda7        13454b41-7ab4-44af-bc79-a69efb39b40b   ext4       
/dev/sda8        9d4fe4ed-d07b-4ab3-8157-63551a36860b   ext4       
/dev/sda9 97eb4732-3e09-470f-80f4-b51bbf798b77 ext4
```

Comment: Why you still want to keep windows when you have "Linux"? There are many alternatives and finally mono wine.  But as you are unable to get grub, reinstall grub from live dvd you have.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows may it'd help you.

Comment: Your partitions are showing as SFS which is dynamic. Dynamic is Windows proprietary. Best to use Windows tools to undo the dynamic. http://askubuntu.com/questions/482768/changing-windows-dynamic-disk-partition-to-basic-partition-and-not-the-full-driv or: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2325331&p=13492758&viewfull=1#post13492758