# creating a ext4 partition

Tags: partitioning

I want to make another ext4 partition for my files in ubuntu but because I have both widowns and ubuntu installed when I format the specific drive , in windows it turns out that my hard is converted to a dynamic disk and I cant' access that drive in windows.how to make ext4 partition without that happening ?any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You have to first fully backup and then remove the dynamic partitions. http://askubuntu.com/questions/482768/changing-windows-dynamic-disk-partition-to-basic-partition-and-not-the-full-driv and: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/26829-convert-dynamic-disk-basic-disk.html

Answer (score 1):

If you would like a gui tool I would recommend you use gparted

This is a great tool to easily manage all you partitions.
You can resize, format, delete, etc.

To install type this into the command line

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

To run type this

```
sudo gparted
```

Now you would probably need to shrink your NTFS partition (the one with Windows)

Right-click on it and select resize or move.

[image]

Now drag the slider to make space for your new EXT4 partition

[image]

Click the resize or move at the bottom to apply changes.

Now right click on the empty space and select new

[image]

Now choose EXT4 as the partition and click add

[image]

Finally after you have properly formatted your drive with all of its partitions, click the green tick at the top to apply changes.
[image]