# Why can't "Simple" partitions be read in Ubuntu?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, windows

I've been slowly *transitioning* over to Ubuntu and the Linux community as I can see so many ***improvements*** linux has over Windows. I didn't have a problem with these as I used `crouton` and I liked the functions it had.

Now, I want to use another HDD as my /home partition. I made some free space on the Windows end and when I went to see the partition in GNOME Disks or `gnome-disk-utility` and to my expense, it says it is a "Microsoft LDM data" partition of a 1 TB. I've been checking about this and nothing has shown that can help me. It's a "simple partition" and it dosen't work for some reason.

I would love some help. Thanks.

**Edit:** I want to keep my files in that partition.

Comment: Use `gparted` and format the partition to what you need.

Comment: I don't want to delete my games that are stored on that partition. I should have labeled it better.

Comment: No problem: you can at any time edit your question to improve clarity or add relevant information.

Comment: This is not "Simple partitions". You apparently use "Windows Dynamic Disks", which is not anymore simply a Windows partition. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8427372/windows-spanned-disks-ldm-restoration-with-linux to see how one can access such partitions using `ldmtool`.

Comment: Sorry, about that. But it's too complicated. Like I said, I'm new. Sorry, I need to be spoonfed this info. More of this complexity is making me want to just re-download all my games.

Comment: You can't "keep your files" on the partition and install Ubuntu there.

Comment: @Pilot6 Sorry, if you did not understand. But I have Ubuntu, I am using Ubuntu right now. I wanted just to move my /home into a drive that I don't use that much and it has 1 TB of storage. I know how to, but Ubuntu can't understand it. I'm gonna test out K7AAY's solution for now.

Comment: @user68186 I know that but I made some free space for Ubuntu to make a new `ext4` partition.

Comment: Would you please be so kind as to boot into Windows, right-click on the Start icon, choose Disk Management, take a screenshot, upload that to a free image host site like http://imgur.com , then click [edit] and add the link to that into your question? I'd like to see all the detail about that drive you want to repartition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why can't your Dynamic disk partition be read by Ubuntu Linux? Because the nonstandard [LDM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Disk_Manager) partitioning method created by Microsoft is proprietary, and does not play well with others.

There are [multiple methods](https://www.google.com/search?q=convert%20dynamic%20to%20basic%20without%20reformat) to convert your drives back to the standard partitioning method, such as the [first one (only) here](https://askubuntu.com/a/900933/197910), this, [alternative](https://superuser.com/questions/65939/converting-dynamic-to-basic-disk/66065#66065), or [this one](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-hardware/converting-hard-drives-from-dynamic-to-basic/dddcb9c5-20c4-4306-b401-1a7731536f75). You'll need to do that before Linux can see the drive.

However, **ensure to make a complete backup of what's on that drive first, and verify the backup, before you start to make changes.** Disk partition changes are the *easiest* way to lose *all the programs and data* on a drive.

Comment: Sorry, but I have to "pay" first before I can do that apparently.

Comment: Take a look at the new options in the second paragraph of my answer.

Comment: Thank you for the help! This works for me.