# Getting error while installing ubuntu with Windows 10 In Dual boot mode

Tags: boot, 16.04, dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

I am trying to install ubuntu in the windows 10 in dual boot mode, firstly i have created the LIVE USB Pendrive to install. what error i am getting is, Gparted is not detecting my already parted windows drive, I have three drive named C,D,E but what can I see is only one drive is showing that is full 961 Gb out of my 1 TB, I guess that is the usable size. then i took all the backup of my D & E drive and deleted the partition and then created a new one. now when I  tried to install ubuntu so Gparted is showing me wrong partition. I have three Drive with 350 Gb, 281 Gb ( Where i have installed my windows 10 ). 278 Gb. but Gparted is showing me one 680 Gb around partition along with 291 Gb partition, i am unable to shrink size of the any of those drive and i am afraid that if i install in any of these drive so my windows will be corrupt which i don't want. so give me solution what to do now ?

Comment: Often when you use Windows to create partitions it automatically converts to dynamic partitions which are Microsoft proprietary. Are your partitions basic or dynamic. Windows will show you. Also post this: `sudo parted /dev/sda unit s print`

Comment: only one partition where the windows 10 is installed is Dynamic, others are basic only !! I know about the Dynamic Partition where it won't allow more then one OS to be installed. so now tell me what i can do to install Ubuntu ? I don't have such time to uninstall Windows 10 and install Ubuntu and then create partition and install Windows.

Comment: Use Windows third party tools to convert Widnows partition. https://askubuntu.com/questions/482768/changing-windows-dynamic-disk-partition-to-basic-partition-and-not-the-full-driv Also: EASEUS Partition Master  or MiniTool Then reboot Windows and make sure fast start up is off. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions Use Windows to shrink the Windows NTFS partition & reboot so it can run chkdsk. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions &  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: Man, Believe me, I have tried all of this, but nothing is working !! I have used EPM but it is showing me same problem,

Comment: Post your partitions from Linux.