# Can't install ubuntu 16.10 alongside windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, uefi

I can't seem to install ubuntu 16.10 (or any 17.10, or 16.04) on my drive.

I have disabled fast boot, and turned off hibernation with `powercfg /h off`

[image: power]

Here is a screenshot of my disk from `diskmgmt.msc`  I want to install ubuntu on the 137gb unallocated space partition.

[image: Partitions]

I have disabled secure boot, and have made a bootable usb with unetbootin.
When I boot to the usb, it says that I "Might have other operating systems in the legacy bios mode."  then when I click on `something else`, the partitions don't seem to be there, it's just a single 1TB partition.

I don't think this has anything to do with dynamic disks, since diskmgmt says it's a basic disk.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

---

Edit: I left out that the computer is an Alienware 17r.  After googling a bit more about that specific computer, I changed from "Raid on" in the BIOS settings to "AHCI".  This solved the problems I was having with the installer not detecting my partitions, however, after "installing alongside windows", The installer says it can't install something from the CD rom.  I click ok, then it says it's done.  I click reboot, and the installer freezes.  Then if i reboot the computer, nothing changes and there is no option to boot into the newly installed linux partition.

Comment: 16.10 is end of life, so you shouldn't install it on anything, btw.

Comment: @dobey thanks, I want 17.10 anyways, but was trying older things just to check.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing Windows dynamic disk partition to basic partition and not the full drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/482768/changing-windows-dynamic-disk-partition-to-basic-partition-and-not-the-full-driv)

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate since diskmgmt says my drive is basic.  Which is what it should be right?

Answer (score -1):

When choosing to boot to the flash drive make sure to select the same BIOS mode either UEFI or BIOS that matches the windows instillation. You can usually find what mode your in the boot options of your BIOS. It should show boot using UEFI, BIOS or Both.

Comment: I'm fairly certain I am choosing UEFI (which matches what my windows installation is in) when booting from the USB, but is there any way to check that once i'm in the ubuntu install menu?

Comment: I dont think there is a way to check in the installation menu but you can make a UEFI only boot image by following these instructions   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick#Creating_an_EFI-only_image

Comment: Shows install with screen shots. Both BIOS purple accessibility screen & UEFI black grub menu screen, so you know which way you have booted. UEFI itself should have two boot options and normally UEFI option is clearly labeled. BIOS option may just be name/label of flash drive.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: I boot the usb drive that's clearly labeled UEFI, It boots to the black screen and asks if I want to try ubuntu or install it, and i select install.