# Second HDD not seen

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, gparted

I have a lenovo Y910 AIO 27in and i recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 on the primary SSD drive (Clean install no Windows dual boot). The problem is that the secondary 2TB HDD is not visible on the file manager and when i go to Gparted i can see the drive as LDM partitions. I have data stored in the drive and i don't want to reformat it or dual boot Windows to transfer my data. Is there any way i can mount the drive?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. You may find this useful: https://askubuntu.com/questions/482768/changing-windows-dynamic-disk-partition-to-basic-partition-and-not-the-full-driv

Comment: Add the output of `lsblk -o NAME,SIZE,FSTYPE,TYPE,MOUNTPOINT`

Comment: Thank you all. I reinstalled windows backup my files, turn the disk to basic again. Reinstalled Ubuntu. Works great.