# Lubuntu with ldmtool cannot see LDM partitions on GPT disk

Tags: lubuntu

I have Lubuntu/Windows 10 dual boot on a computer with 1 SSD and 2 HDDs. The HDD in question is the 1T disk in the screen capture below; it is a GPT Dynamic disk created under Windows. I have many files on it, also created under Windows. I would like to access its content from Lubuntu but I don't need Lubuntu to modify the partitions - I just need read/write access to the files.

In Lubuntu, before and after I install `ldmtool`, I get the same thing in `Disks`:

[image]

So "old OS" shows up as **one** mounted partition. In file manager, at that mount point, I see:

[image]

However I am expecting **two** partitions for that total size at that location on that disk. And inside the two partitions I should have many folders other than just these two.

`ldm scan /dev/sdb`, `ldm scan /dev/sdb*`, `ldm scan /dev/sdb5`, and `ldmtool create all` all return [].

I found [documentation dated 2007](http://www.infradead.org/~mchehab/kernel_docs/unsorted/ldm.html) that said the Linux LDM driver did not support "LDM on top of a GPT label disk". I wonder whether this is the cause of my problem 11 years later.

Other than going to Windows and copying everything out (I have tried converting that disk to basic; all free tools refuse to do so), is there a way for me to access my data on this disk?

Thanks. Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: It used to be that Linux did not see dynamic partitions at all. Then drivers were updated. With MBR, the third party tools did work to remove dynamic partitions. Dynamic was originally a proprietary Microsoft work around for the 4  primary partition limit with MBR. Not idea why anyone would want dynamic with gpt since limit is 128 partitions. Since you need good backups anyway, back up system and see if this works: https://askubuntu.com/questions/482768/changing-windows-dynamic-disk-partition-to-basic-partition-and-not-the-full-driv