# Can't read partition using GParted

Tags: partitioning, gparted, external-hdd

I removed a HDD from an old laptop from 2013 running Windows 7. I'm trying to access to its data but I cant either mount its partitions or manage them using GParted.

GParted shows the following errors when I refresh devices:

```
Libparted error: Can't have a partition outside the disk! (rises multiple times)
Libparted error: Invalid argument during seek for read on /dev/sdf (rises multiple times)
Libparted error: Invalid partition table on /dev/sdf -- wrong signature 0. (this one only rises once).
```

If I push "ignore error" until it stops, GParted shows the following:

[State of gparted when trying to read the disk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XPBO.png)

Accessing the information flags for each partition shows the following warning:

```
Unable to detect file system! Possible reasons are:
- The file system is damaged 
- The file system is unknown to GParted
- There is no file system available (unformatted)
- The device entry /dev/sdf4 is missing

Invalid argument during seek for read on /dev/sdf
```

Any idea how to repair/access to my device without replugping it to the old PC?

Comment: Actually the file systems are either damaged or are dynamic disks. Either way you won't be able to read them in Linux. In the first case use Windows native error correction tools to try to salvage something. In the second case only Windows can read it.

Comment: You can produce English messages by `LANG=C sudo gparted`

Comment: @waltinator It says "unknown" in all partitions. I suspect it has to do with dynamic disks.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments. I reran gparted in English and updated the warning logs and the screenshot. @GabrielaGarcia I will close / update the post if I find anything new after following your advice :).

Comment: Best to have good backups, but you may be able to convert back to basic partitions. See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/482768/changing-windows-dynamic-disk-partition-to-basic-partition-and-not-the-full-driv