# while installing ubuntu 19.04 no partiton is showing

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted, 19.04

I tried to install ubuntu 19.04 in my friend laptop. His laptop is lenovo g580 with 4gb ram. I have created a free disk partition of 280gb.[image: photo from windows disk management]

But when i try to install ubuntu in his laptop i get to see no partition available for installing. So i got to check the gparted which shows as [image: From gparted]

I dont know what to do now. I have serched for the internet where i cannot find a reasonable solution. So what should i do ?

Comment: This is because the Dynamic type of partitions.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/482768/changing-windows-dynamic-disk-partition-to-basic-partition-and-not-the-full-driv

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/348527/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-a-windows-dynamic-disk-mbr-scheme

Comment: Please be aware that you are likely not correctly shutting down Windows 10 and it's actually leaving the disk into a hibernated state. This means you can install Ubuntu and then go back into Windows and it will write corrupted information in the disk because it was resumed from hibernation.

Answer (score 1):

**PLAN A:**

Back up everything he has then verify it.
Twice. 
You don't want to lose his data.

Collect his Windows 10 recovery / installation media and all media required to reinstall his apps. Also collect his installation keys.

[Convert the Dynamic Disk to Basic Disks](https://askubuntu.com/questions/482768/changing-windows-dynamic-disk-partition-to-basic-partition-and-not-the-full-driv).

Then you can install Ubuntu.

**PLAN B:**

Or, get a [physically small USB 3.0 USB drive](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01LFV52W8) and make a [Lubuntu 19.04](https://lubuntu.me/downloads/) [LiveUSB with Persistance](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/14912/create-a-persistent-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive/). I say Lubuntu because it's faster with small memory. Put in in one of his USB 3 ports and he can boot from it, read from, and write to NTFS, and get an idea what Linux is all about.