# Ubuntu won't show any file in NTFS HDD

Tags: dual-boot, disk, ntfs-3g

After adding Ubuntu for dual boot with Windows 10, it boots from the SSD, but files in my HDD (D:) can not be detected. That drive is mounted but empty. how to fix it?  See screenshots:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/V36cD.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9F2H.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2of5L.jpg
thanks

Comment: Most common issue is Windows fast start up which also sets hibernation flag or hibernation. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation Could also be that partition needs chkdsk which you can only run from Windows for NTFS formats.

Comment: Just noticed you are showing LDM partition type. That is dynamic disks with gpt partitioning and is proprietary, so Linux does not work with it. https://askubuntu.com/questions/482768/changing-windows-dynamic-disk-partition-to-basic-partition-and-not-the-full-driv Also with Acer you may need additional settings. Acer Aspire E15 will not dual boot, many details Trust settings in step 35
http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot
Acer Nitro 7 Missing AHCI mode Ctrl + S in UEFI
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2429951&p=13900969#post13900969