# SSD is functioning on Windows, but not Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, ssd, ntfs

My setup: I have **Windows 10** and **Ubuntu 18.04 LTS** in **dual boot**, both on different Hard Drives. 
I have a **third SSD** that I'm trying to use **on both systems for simple storage**, but Ubuntu is not recognizing it correctly. (On Windows I **do not** experience any problems using it.)

What I tried so far:

```
fdisk -l
parted -l
testdisk
```

None of the above shows the drive (should be `/dev/sdc/`. There are some `/dev/loop/` drives but those are related to my forth windows dynamic disk I think.)

```
gparted
```

**Sometimes** shows it, but I'm greeted with never ending errors, I have to spam click away. Cannot reproduce it right now but I remember it wanted me to add a new partition table but failed doing so.

```
ntfs-3g
ntfsfix
```

Errors about missing boot sector?

I spent days in search for a solution but did not come across one that worked for me so I made a new post. Most of the times people say the drive is malfunctioning but I am confused why it is working flawlessly on windows than.
Also BIOS is showing the drive as well.

Any ideas?

Comment: Loop devices are snaps. Most often issue is Windows fast start up which sets hibernation flag on every NTFS partition. Then Ubuntu NTFS driver will not open NTFS to prevent damage. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation
Could also be the NTFS needs chkdsk. Also have you updated firmware for your ssd and UEFI firmware?

Comment: I disabled the windows feature but no luck. I was randomly able to get the gparted error again: "fsycnc of /dev/sdcX/ failed: input/output error". UEFI is on newest firmware, ssd does not provide any software.

Comment: If drive is dynamic, LInux will not open it. Even some Windows tools do not work with dynamic partitions. https://askubuntu.com/questions/482768/changing-windows-dynamic-disk-partition-to-basic-partition-and-not-the-full-driv Other options also Aomei or even testdisk if only 4 dynamic partitions:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/482768/changing-windows-dynamic-disk-partition-to-basic-partition-and-not-the-full-driv