# My NTFS partitions are being showed as LDM Data Partitions

Tags: partitioning, ntfs, format, microsoft

I've just installed Ubuntu and completely replaced my Windows 10 because I don't want to use it anymore. Installation went very well and everything is working fine but one issue is that I've installed Ubuntu on my SSD drive that seems to work fine but I've another 2TB disk and its partitions are not being recognized by Ubuntu. It just shows as LDM data partition. Please kindly help me fix this, I've lots of important data in that drive and I don't have any backup.

Following is the screenshot of that 2TB drive of "Disks" tool.

[Disks tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5JHQ.png)

EDIT:This is the output of fdisk -l /dev/sda

```
Disk /dev/sda: 1.84 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Disk model: ST2000LM007-1R81
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 11265FFB-2E2C-4395-83C0-5935F7822AF7

Device       Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1       34       2081       2048    1M Microsoft LDM metadata
/dev/sda2     2082     262177     260096  127M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda4  1128448 3907029134 3905900687  1.8T Microsoft LDM data

Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.
```

Comment: Please post the output of sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda

Comment: "I've lots of important data in that drive" then you have backups. "and I don't have any backup." Then stop calling that data important and start making backups. You really took a very big gamble installing Ubuntu without a backup. I'd get fired if I did that (even if things went perfect: since that risk was avoidable it should have been avoided). I refuse to help unless you made a backup :=)

Comment: LDM is a proprietary Windows partitioning, something like LVM in Linux. Windows has no undo. You have to have good backups, but some third party Windows tools claim to convert without data loss. There is now a Linux tool that may let you see data to back it up. http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/ldmtool.1.html See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/482768/changing-windows-dynamic-disk-partition-to-basic-partition-and-not-the-full-driv

Comment: LDMTool does not work it just shows [ ] for everything :(

Comment: @Rinzwind - While I agree with you, the backup he did not do, cannot be done.

Comment: Connect the 2TB disk to a Windows computer, backup your data, then reconnect the disk to your primary computer, re-init it and create a ext4 partition, restore your data.

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio don't care. if data is important you make backups. There is NO way around that. And you make them periodically. and know how to restore. No excuses. Unless the data is not that important then we don't care. But calling data important and not having a backup is in insult to that data ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you did not mess with your data yet, you should first make a backup.
You could connect it to a Windows system and backup, as mentioned by heynnema.

You would need another disk.
In some cases, you could split your data partition to have one as a backup (if the space taken by data were less than 1Tb), and then work on your original data partition.
In this case yo cannot do that, since you would not be able later to change the partition type of only one partition.

Then you can reformat your disk, and recover the data.