# My Ubuntu is not showing my HDD..Only SSD is showing

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, ssd

Mine is a hybrid laptop. It has 256 GB SSD and 1 TB HDD. I replaced the Windows in SSD with Ubuntu, and it was a success. But when I logged in and open files my HDD is not showing I dont know what to do. My all backup files are in the HDD. I installed GParted and my HDD is showing there, but some error is showing..The image of GParted is below.enter image description here

[image]

[image]

please help me out!!!!

Comment: Open a ternial and type `cd /dev` then type `ls` and see if sda5 shows up.

Comment: And if it is, go to your windoze install and use one of the disk tools to confirm the file system i.e. FAT or NTFS etc. Then you can go back to your Ubuntu install, open a terminal and type `mount -t ntfs /dev/sda5  /mnt/` assuming it was an ntfs file system.

Comment: Ok lemme check if it works

Comment: wait how to check if its ntfs or fat..Where should I check it

Comment: LDM is a Microsoft thing that will not work with Linux. See here. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1227009/my-ntfs-partitions-are-being-showed-as-ldm-data-partitions You need clone the entire disk, connect that to a Windows machine and recover the data there

Comment: hmmm okay I will do it