# Cannot see my internal Hard Disk

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, 22.04, ssd

I'm a newbie and moved from Windows 10 to Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS. I installed Ubuntu to my 120GB SSD and other personal files are on my internal 1 TB HDD. After installing Ubuntu, I can only see the SSD drive and its contents but not my HDD drive.

Please help me to so I can access my HDD.

[image: lsblk command]

[image: HDD Not Shown on Files]

[image: HDD Shown on Disk utility]

Comment: Please be precise with details; Ubuntu products using the *year* format (eg. Ubuntu Core 22) are different to the far more widely used *year.month* product (eg. Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Server).  22 is a *flavor* of Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Server.  Is your windows a *clean* disk (ie. not a *hibernated* system which includes *fastboot* as that is an *unclean* disk with parts of file-system stored in the fastboot/hibernate file)

Comment: Updated the Ubuntu version on description.  And not sure about what you are asking about windows. On my HDD I has only my personal file like medias and other developing software.

Comment: Do you know if Bitlocker was used (or any other form of encryption) on your hdd when it was used in Windows? Also, I assume fast start up wasn’t disabled … did you shut down Windows completely (not hibernate) when you closed it for the last time?

Comment: No any encryption was used when i was using windows. And windows was shutdown when i closed it last time.

Comment: What happens if you try to mount it? You should find you disk using sudo fdisk -l

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that that disk has used Windows proprietry LDM partitions:
see this link [My NTFS partitions are being showed as LDM Data Partitions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1227009/my-ntfs-partitions-are-being-showed-as-ldm-data-partitions) (the comment from oldfred is probably more useful than the answer).

It's not straightforward to access that drive from Ubuntu.

You have a few options:

(1) Use a tool to access that data (eg ldmtool): This link may help you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8427372/windows-spanned-disks-ldm-restoration-with-linux

(2) Reformat the drive and copy your data back from backup. To format the drive, click on the gear cog at the bottom left on Disks and you should get options to create partitions / format the drive.

(3) If you don't have a backup (but you really should!), your safest option is to use Windows to access the data, back it up then format in Ubuntu. Either (1) remove the drive and put it in a Windows machine - I think you should be able to access it then - or (2) reinstall Windows on your SSD, access your HDD's data, copy it externally and then reinstall Ubuntu and copy the data across.

Do let us know how you get on.