# Dual Boot Installation of Ubuntu Budgie 18.04 alongside Windows 8.1

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8, ubuntu-budgie

I am trying to install Ubuntu Budgie alongside my Windows 8.1 but I'm facing some issues.

I have Windows 8.1 on my laptop with three partitions as can be seen in the attached screenshot. I have created an unallocated space of 100GB. Now, when I start the installation process of Ubuntu, I don't see the option "Install Ubuntu Budgie alongside Windows 8.1" and when I select "Something else" option, I don't see free space which I have already created. I have been searching for a proper solution but nothing works.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You have dynamic partitions which is proprietary to Microsoft. There now is a Linux driver to see dynamic but still does not work well. Windows 8 was supposed to only be installed by vendors in UEFI boot mode, but it looks like you may have BIOS boot? https://askubuntu.com/questions/482768/changing-windows-dynamic-disk-partition-to-basic-partition-and-not-the-full-driv Shown as SFS in fdisk, Dynamic also on gpt as LDM
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365449%28v=vs.85%29.aspx & 
http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/26829-convert-dynamic-disk-basic-disk.html

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes my system has BIOS boot. I changed my drive from dynamic to basic. Now the partition is marked as logical and I installed Ubuntu on it :)