# Can't mount hdd: Edit mount options grays out

Tags: disk, disk-usage, disk-management, disk-utility, gnome-disk-utility

I have installed ubuntu 20.04 in my Lenovo ideapad s145-14iwl laptop. I am a new user of ubuntu. After opening disk app, i can see the hdd but can't mount it through edit mount option as it has grayed out. The partition on hdd is not showing. It shows as single partition.[here is the image of the disk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0HOo.png)
Plz help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It may help to post a screenshot of the disks application. That may help to see what is going on.

Comment: I have added the screenshot.

Comment: Where did you install Ubuntu ? On the 240 GB disk ? The 1 TB disk that you show,  has one partition in "Microsoft LDM data" format, that possibly can't be mounted in Ubuntu/Linux. What do you want to mount ?

Comment: I installed ubuntu on 240GB disk. Nd want to mount 1 TB disk.

Comment: LDM is a proprietary protocol of MS to manage dynamic partitions. Check lmtool, a recent tool designed to work with the format: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8427372/windows-spanned-disks-ldm-restoration-with-linux

Comment: How did microsoft get in there? Are you dual booting?

Comment: Yes. Along with windows 10.

Comment: Best to just remove the proprietary Microsoft LDM. You need good backups. Microsoft has no undo, but some third party tools should work. https://askubuntu.com/questions/482768/changing-windows-dynamic-disk-partition-to-basic-partition-and-not-the-full-driv