# GRUB Bootloader Screen

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, system-installation

I recently installed Ubuntu on my PC. When I boot up my PC the regular way (e.g. pressing the power button), it shows a boot loader screen, like the problem https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-fix-minimal-bash-like-line-editing-is-supported-grub-error-in-linux/ tries to solve. I followed it but failed to find my linux partition (it showed a bunch of hd0s which are all my windows disk). I am using a workaround where I booted into the BIOS first and then entered Ubuntu from there pressing the shift button which allowed me to boot into Ubuntu or my windows without seeing the GRUB screen. How do I solve the problem without this workaround?

(I have two physical disks: one with Ubuntu and one with Windows. GRUB failed to find the one with Ubuntu so I can't boot from there. (But I think BIOS can that's how the workaround works))

(Also, I can boot into Ubuntu through the BIOS, and I did follow the last step of the tutorial. It didn't work.)

Comment: What brand/model system? Are both installed in UEFI boot mode? May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: I'm quite new to this. I'm using a Legion PC with AMD CPU and graphics. I am not sure what you mean by everything else. I didn't use boot repair, are you telling me not to?

Comment: Is this yours, please copy clickable link in question.  https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/WQmtZvqqBF/. You show UEFI Secure Boot on, which should work, but often easier with it off. But you also have Windows fast startup on. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation
You show only one drive, but have LDM/SFS which is proprietary to Microsoft. https://askubuntu.com/questions/482768/changing-windows-dynamic-disk-partition-to-basic-partition-and-not-the-full-driv

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you have disabled Legacy boot option and secure boot from BIOS settings. It's fairly easy to disable

Create live USB stick of the Ubuntu version you have installed on the system.

Boot using the live UBS stick, select **Try Ubuntu** option. You should have internet connectivity to perform below steps:

- Open the terminal
- Execute following commands.

  > sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair 
  > sudo apt-get update 
  > sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
- Popup will appear, select recommended repair

Comment: I got paste.ubuntu.com/p/WQmtZvqqBF/.

Comment: Also I cannot boot into Ubuntu anymore. (BIOS thinks my two disks are one disk so I can't set boot priority, and it simply ignores Ubuntu now.)