# Can only see partial partition in dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I have a dual boot computer with Kubuntu 20.04 and win 10 on my system. I have a total of 4 partitions in windows. One for C drive and rest for my personal files (D drive, E drive,and F drive). These partitions are working perfectly fine in windows.

But when I log into Kubuntu, I can only see C drive and D drive. I am unable to locate E drive and F drive.

I have hybrid storage on my system (HDD - 1 TB and SSD - 512 GB). Both the OS are installed on SSD and HDD contains the D, E, and F drive. The Screenshot of the lsblk-f is attached. The sda1 and sda2 are not E drive and F drive.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: LDM is what is shown for dynamic partitions. With UEFI and gpt partitioning there is no reason for dynamic partitions that I know of. But only recently do you even see those exist with Linux. Microsoft's official policy is a full backup, erase dynamic partitions and create new basic partitions. There is no undo, but they make it easy to convert to dynamic partitions. Some third party Windows tools can undo, but you still need good backups, just in case.https://askubuntu.com/questions/482768/changing-windows-dynamic-disk-partition-to-basic-partition-and-not-the-full-driv

Comment: @oldfred Are you suggesting me to delete the partition and create a new one. My whole HDD is showing dynamic.

Comment: Its all or nothing. Either entire drive is LDM or basic. I would look into the third party tools to convert which may keep your data, but you still need good backups.

Comment: I would try that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are the E: and F: partitions also NTFS?

In Windows, in an administrative command window, type:

`chkdsk /f E:`

`chkdsk /f F:`

Reboot to Ubuntu and retry accessing these partitions.

**Update #1:**

I'm not sure why you can read one dynamic NTFS partition, but not the other two. The good news is that you don't appear to have much data on an of D:/E:/F:, so backup any data, and then remove the partitions, and recreate them as BASIC NTFS partitions, and then you should be able to access them via Ubuntu.

*I deleted all the partitions and created new partitions. Now it is working perfectly fine.*

Comment: Yes, the partitions are NTFS. I ran the chkdsk and it scanned the disk without any error. But still, I am unable to access these partitions in ubuntu.

Comment: @Sam I'm not sure why you can read one dynamic NTFS partition, but not the other two. The good news is that you don't appear to have much data on an of D:/E:/F:, so backup any data, and then remove the partitions, and recreate them as BASIC NTFS partitions, and then you should be able to access them via Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I deleted all the partitions and created new partitions. Now it is working perfectly fine.