# Dual boot Ubuntu setup - missing/invalid HDD after successful installation

Tags: dual-boot, hard-drive, ssd

I am new to Linux world. I am trying to dual boot my machine for Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows 10. I have done the rest of the setup accurately and I can boot to both the OS successfully. But when I check my drives I see my 1 TB HDD is invalid and some of its partitions are missing.
I have windows installed on SSD and Ubuntu on HDD. I used /dev/sda/ boot loader. When I boot to windows and look for HDD it only shows SSD and the HDD- Disk 0 is shown invalid as well as few partitions of it are shown as missing. At this point, I am not sure if my Ubuntu is actually using HDD or SSD. Please help me to fix this issue OR help me diagnose this issue so that I can figure out how to fix this. I appreciate any suggestions given regarding partitions and dual boot to avoid further complications.

Comment: Welcome! Don't use windows to check disks or partitions, since it cannot see properly EXT file systems. In Ubuntu, opend Disks application and you will see all the disks' information. Ubuntu is installed under an EXT format filesystem, windows under NTFS.

Comment: Bring up the terminal (R. click desktop), then run this command - `sudo parted -l`. Post output into your question.

Comment: Model: ATA ST1000LM035-1RK1 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End     Size    File system     Name                Flags
 3      135MB  850GB   850GB   ntfs            LDM data partition
 4      850GB  881GB   30.7GB  ext4
 5      881GB  885GB   4000MB  linux-swap(v1)
 6      885GB  885GB   308MB   fat32                               boot, esp
 7      885GB  1000GB  115GB   ext4

Comment: LDM data partition is an issue. That is dynamic partitions in Windows which only recently can even be seen with Linux. https://askubuntu.com/questions/482768/changing-windows-dynamic-disk-partition-to-basic-partition-and-not-the-full-driv & http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2325331&p=13492758&viewfull=1#post13492758

Comment: Your 1 TB disk is shown clearly in *parted* command. It shows a 850GB LDM Windows partition, 30.7GB and 115GB Linux partitions, 4GB swap and 308MB EFI partition. At a guess it seems that Ubuntu is on the HDD. **Nothing is being shown for your SSD**, that is if you posted all output for the command. And Windows cannot read *ext4* partitions anyway.

Comment: Thank you for your information everyone I understand it better now