# Fix dynamic disk problem of dual boot Ubuntu 18.04 alongside Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, windows-10

My computer has an HDD and an SSD. Windows 10 is installed on the SSD. I want to install Ubuntu 18.04 as a dual boot on the HDD, so I made a new volume and left it "Unallocated". Then I booted via USB to Ubuntu and selected the Install option. It's there the possibility of custom installation that you choose where to install it.

The default is to install Ubuntu on my SSD on which I do not want to put it, so I created the volume. The volume should show as "Free Space" in the Ubuntu installer, but it says that there is only 1MB free. I went looking for something and I read that Linux does not have support for [dynamic disks](http://techgenix.com/basic-disk-dynamic-disk-convert/) which I currently have, so I need to convert from Dynamic disk to Basic disk so that I can install Ubuntu, but the instructions say that I have to delete all volumes in order to convert from dynamic to basic. I'm not sure if "System Partition and Recovery Partition" can be deleted.

Comment: UEFI or BIOS or more correctly MBR(msdos) or gpt. Windows only boots in UEFI mode from gpt and only BIOS from MBR. Microsoft's solution is total backup, erase system, create new partitions with new install & restore data. You need good backups. Some third party Windows tools may work, but you still need good backups. https://askubuntu.com/questions/482768/changing-windows-dynamic-disk-partition-to-basic-partition-and-not-the-full-driv & https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2325331&p=13492758&viewfull=1#post13492758

Comment: Hey ! Thanks for answer. So I have my system installed on SSD drive (Windows) , and i want install Ubuntu on HDD , so I downloaded 3rd party tool called PW , and it says that i need delete :E partition to convert disk . Because my Dynamic disk is in two parts you know same letter same name (one is 500gb and 2nd is 400gb. = 1TB). SO do you think deleting will solve my problem?

Comment: Do not know tool you are using. But if BIOS/MBR there is the 4 primary partition limit. Most use one primary partition as an extended partition which then acts as a container for as many logical partitions as you want. With gpt there is no limit on primary partitions (really 128, but even that can be changed).If deleting a partition be sure you have good backup. Post this in question: `sudo parted -l` and 'sudo fdisk -lu`