# Horrific state to be in. Can't install Ubuntu due to HDD issues? HELP!

Tags: boot, partitioning

I am trying to install Ubuntu onto a machine with an installed Win10. In the "Something Else" section I can't find my windows C: drive so that I can delete it and say goodbye and install Linux

Relevant specifications:

- BIOS Legacy, not UEFI
- 1 HDD which is Dynamic
- 4 partitions
  (1. system, 2. custom with my data, 3. and another custom one with my
  data which is for some reason split into 2 with the same letter in
  the disk manager, but not in the My PC window = 4 in total)
- The pen drive was formatted with a BIOS target.

**What I already know using google:**

I. I can't use a dynamic Drive. I need a basic HDD. But how is it possible if I only have one HDD with Windows on it? How do I convert it if it needs to be empty, yet I need windows to do the conversion?

II. My system can only handle 4 partitions at a time, so I guess I can't create one, which I understand, but at the same time why would I not be able to delete one and create one? (4 - 1 + 1 = 4)

**What I want to know:**

1. How do I make my pc just simply install Linux without windows? I am currently scooping my data 250GB to another PC with a "teaspoon" 8GB flash drive, so keeping the data is not a concern. In a day or so...
   1.1 Is it going to be enough if I just simply choose the option "Erase disk and Install" instead of "Something Else"? How will Linux handle the partitions? Will the hidden windows partition be visible for the Linux in this case, so it can wipe it away? How it will handle the partitioning? Create one big partition? Ideally, I would want to have 100gigs for the system and the rest for myself. I guess I can do this afterwards?
2. Or should I do something before doing Erase disk and Install? Some disk management on the windows I have still currently running? Wipe all except windows and do something with that?

Thanks for reading and trying to help!

Comment: Usually you need to use Windows tools, but testdisk may work. Other options also Aomei or even testdisk if only 4 dynamic partitions:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/482768/changing-windows-dynamic-disk-partition-to-basic-partition-and-not-the-full-driv More info: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2325331&p=13492758&viewfull=1#post13492758  If newer UEFI system, better to install in UEFI boot mode with gpt partitioning which eliminates the 4 partition limit.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I make my pc just simply install Linux without windows?

"Erase disk and install Ubuntu" is indeed the correct option and handles the automatic partitioning just fine, unless you have a specific idea how you'd like to partition your own disk.

Comment: I mean I would like to configure the partitioning myself, but it doesn't work with the way my HDD is set up right now.
So even if I don't have access to my disc C: where my windows is at, Ubuntu is still going to be able to handle the partitioning just fine?
I mean if Ubuntu doesn't have access to the system partition at installation time, it might also not be able to get it in the formatting process?

Comment: @SugarIsNotHealthy Do you intend to keep Windows as well?  If not, then going into "Something Else", selecting your drive, and hitting 'Create Partition Table' will blast away all Windows partition table references, then you can partition your system to your heart's content.  It will effectively obliterate the Windows partition schemes it was doing with dynamic disks.

Comment: @ThomasWard I got enough of windows, so no, i dont want to keep it. I want it off my machine! Will this method keep data on the other partitions?

Comment: @SugarIsNotHealthy no, you would need to convert those to non-dynamic partitions in Windows first.  Or, go into Windows, backup your data on an external drive, then create your partitions and restore your data after the fact.

Comment: @ThomasWard but in order to convert them to nondynamic, I need to delete them in windows, but how am I going to do that if it wont have windows in the end?
About your last sentence. If I had access to at least the system partition, I would have already done it. But it doesnt appear in the "Something else" section. All I have is 2 partitions with my data (determined by size). Another one is windows boot, and the last one, which should have been the system one, but it is 500mb in size. So I dont have access. Will the "Erase disk and Install" option also format the unreachable system partition?

Comment: @SugarIsNotHealthy it will (and should) overwrite the entire disk's partition scheme yes, but any data on the data partitions will be irretrievable after that is changed.