# Windows partition is not showing in Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, ssd

I have a double booted system with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04. I have two disk: 256GB SSD and 1TB HDD. my HDD has two partitions in Windows with name new volume D and E but in Ubuntu files system only data of new volume D is shown and not showing my data of new volume E
and there is only two disk showing correctly SSD and new volume.
But where is my data of new volume E?

```
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda           8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1        8:1    0     1M  0 part 
├─sda2        8:2    0    15M  0 part 
├─sda3        8:3    0 843.2G  0 part /media/vaibh/New Volume
├─sda4        8:4    0   513M  0 part 
└─sda5        8:5    0  87.9G  0 part /
nvme0n1     259:0    0 238.5G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   260M  0 part /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0    16M  0 part 
└─nvme0n1p3 259:3    0 238.2G  0 part /media/vaibh/Windows


sudo fdisk -lu
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 238.49 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Disk model: SK hynix BC501 HFM256GDJTNG-8310A       
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 7AFFDE2F-3916-4BFD-A5F9-5BA42C276601

Device          Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1   2048    534527    532480   260M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2 534528    567295     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/nvme0n1p3 567296 500115455 499548160 238.2G Microsoft basic data


Disk /dev/sda: 931.53 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: WDC WD10SPZX-80Z
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 59317932-D48A-44A3-957E-0572DA715CE9

Device          Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1          34       2081       2048     1M Microsoft LDM metadata
/dev/sda2        2082      32767      30686    15M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda3       32768 1768253439 1768220672 843.2G Microsoft LDM data
/dev/sda4  1768253440 1769304063    1050624   513M EFI System
/dev/sda5  1769304064 1953523711  184219648  87.9G Linux filesystem

Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.
```

Comment: Please edit the question and add the output of `lsblk`. (If possible without the many `loop` lines)

Comment: Most often issue is that you have Windows fast start up on. Did you turn it off. But it also turns back on with updates, so double check when issues. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation Other issues could be if you converted to dynamic from basic partitions. Post this: `sudo fdisk -lu`. Are drives set for AHCI? Have you updated UEFI and SSD firmware as  that can be  an issue. `lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,LABEL,MOUNTPOINT,SIZE,fsused,MODEL | egrep -v "^loop"`

Comment: Please format any text from terminal you add, so it is legible.

Comment: please help me guys im beginner and its very hard for me because i dont have resurces to learn ubuntu.

Comment: `/dev/sda3       32768 1768253439 1768220672 843.2G Microsoft LDM data`  Your partition is Dynamic and you won't be able to mount it properly in Ubuntu.

Comment: There exists a package named `ldmtool`, a tool for managing Windows dynamic discs. I've never used this, so I can't give more details, but this may be a very useful hint.

Comment: LDM is dynamic partitions. Best to convert back to basic. Drive is already gpt, so not sure why using LDM? Did you do that, somehow. Dynamic was primarily a work around for the old MBR 4 primary partition limit, but with gpt the limit is 128 partitions. See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/482768/changing-windows-dynamic-disk-partition-to-basic-partition-and-not-the-full-driv Best to use Windows third partition tools to undo dymamic partitions. Microsoft makes it easy to create and has no undo.