# Is it possible to convert Dynamic Disk to Basic Disk in Ubuntu 18.04 without data loss?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, lubuntu, disk-management

During a failed attempt to set up dual boot (Lubuntu and Windows 7) on my computer, I had converted my Basic Disk to Dynamic Disk. Now Windows cannot access any file on the drive and diskpart shows it as invalid disk. I have access to Lubuntu 18.04 Live USB which CAN mount the partitons on the disk. I would like to convert the Dynamic Disks to Basic Disk in Lubuntu without losing the data. How do I do it?

Comment: Take a look at the answers [for this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/482768/changing-windows-dynamic-disk-partition-to-basic-partition-and-not-the-full-driv). When working with partitions for other operating systems, there is always a risk of losing data. The tools have gotten better over the years, but I do hope you have a semi-recent backup available just in case 

Comment: @Matigo But I can access the disk in Lubuntu. So why can't I convert it?

Comment: I’m not saying you can’t, I’m saying there is always risk when adapting a partition that is designed for a different operating system. If you can access the partition in Lubuntu, do yourself a favour and copy your most important files. If the partition is converted to basic without problems, then you don’t need he backup. If the partition breaks, then you do. Always be prepared 

Comment: @Matigo Ok. Thanks.

Comment: Should always use an OS's own tools to do anything with it, trying to use another OS's tools to work can and does add problems.