# How do I mount a hard drive other than the one containing Ubuntu on startup?

Tags: dual-boot, mount, hard-drive

[image]

Recently I dual-booted Ubuntu alongside Windows 10 on my SSD rather than my HDD and now I am facing this issue.

I tried a method to view if the disk was visible or not but this message came.
What should I do?

I am getting another message when I try the other way.

[image]

Kindly provide your thoughts to my problem.

This is Ubuntu 20.04.2.

Comment: I'm able to view only the SSD.

Comment: please don't add comments to your question if you have further info, [edit] your question instead.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the figure in the actual question. For terminal ouput, do not use a figure. Instead, copy and paste the terminal output in your question, then format it as console text (using the {} button).

Comment: LDM is Windows proprietary dynamic volume management. Not really compatible. There now is a driver to read LDM, but best just to remove the LDM, if dual booting. (and best to remove even if just running Windows). Shown as SFS in fdisk, Dynamic also on gpt as LDM https://askubuntu.com/questions/482768/changing-windows-dynamic-disk-partition-to-basic-partition-and-not-the-full-driv  & 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365449%28v=vs.85%29.aspx & 
http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/26829-convert-dynamic-disk-basic-disk.html