# missing an entire partition

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, windows, ssd, disk-usage

During the installation process, I chose to not erase the entire disk, so I installed it on  the "C Partition" that I had windows 10 on, and that is after formatting the partition ofc.
so I had 3 partitions untouched 1 for the SSD and another 2 more for the HDD(800 GB & 200GB), but I only found two (the SSD one, and 1 of the 2 HDD), and when I go to "Disks" I see that the HDD is read correctly as 1TB but when I go to files I see that "800 GB" partition only along the size the SSD one, and I can't find away to get this missing partition or even reuse the remaining "200 GB" space.
Thanks in advance.
[Here is the real space of the 1st HDD partition (Main)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqIB9.png)

[Here is the shown space in "Diks"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCJ1l.png)

Edited: Here when I used `lsblk`, you can find the `sda3` read as 1TB, but I only able to see 800gb of it. (The problem is with the `sda` not the `sdb`)

[lsblk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6gHV.png)

Comment: LDM is Windows proprietary dynamic partitions. Something like LVM is in Linux. Windows does not have a way to convert back to standard partitions. But third party Windows tools may work but you must have good backups. https://askubuntu.com/questions/482768/changing-windows-dynamic-disk-partition-to-basic-partition-and-not-the-full-driv You may be able to mount & read the data: https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/ldmtool.1.html

Comment: For me your question is not clear. You are searching partitions? Well open a terminal and type `lsblk` this will list all disks and drives and their partitions. Edit you question and append the output pls. From your pictures I can count several partitions. If you want to get a better visual overview of you disks I suggest to use `sudo partitionmanager` or `sudo gparted` but pls before starting to reformat, move, or expand partitions with those tools, update you question and add some info

Comment: @AlexOnLinux I have 2 Disks, 512GB SSD & 1TB HDD, I had 2 partition for the ssd on windows (200gb, 300gb), and 2 partition for the hdd as well (800gb, 200gb), now after installilng ubuntu everything on the ssd is working fine, but for the hdd one I only see 1 partition (800GB) of the 2 partitions, so there is a entire 200gb partition that I can't find.
I'll my question now

Comment: might it be the case that windows (10) locked the partition? Have alook at this explanation, perhaps it helps: https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-fix-unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation-on-ubuntudebian-and-kali-linux/ and https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Operating-System-and-Recovery/No-disk-Cant-s-see-disk-from-Linux-Boot-Live-Can-t-install/m-p/7183481/highlight/true#M565729

Comment: I don't think it's the same problem here, bc I not even able to locate the partition to try to mount it, plus linux already read the hdd disk and I have already mounted the 800gb partition correctly and it works fine, but the the other one I can't find or even use the 200gb lost space