# Invalid EFI file path after Boot-Repair

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, boot-repair

When I try to boot into Windows I'm getting:

> error: can't find command 'parttool'.
> error can't find command 'drivemap'.
> error: invalid EFI file path.

I tried looking into similar topics, but I'm not sure if the root cause is the same. I was running Windows and Ubuntu on a dual boot successfully for years. Then having reinstalled my Ubuntu the dual boot worked fine for about two days. Then all of a sudden grub couldn't see Windows anymore, so I turned to Boot-Repair, however there were some errors during the process. Now I can at least see the Windows option, but selecting it gives me the above error. I can still boot into Linux at least.

I'm rather confused by my Boot-Repair: log https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/7sRm74x9Rr/

Comment: You have complicated Windows with dynamic partitions - SFS detected on sdb. Now sdc is newer UEFI, but very old MBR. Microsoft has required vendors to install in UEFI boot mode to gpt partitioned drives since 2012. Did you install Windows on sda in BIOS/MBR mode which is intended for old systems? https://askubuntu.com/questions/482768/changing-windows-dynamic-disk-partition-to-basic-partition-and-not-the-full-driv & 
https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=ldmtool You can install BIOS boot version of grub to sdc. But better to totally reinstall Windows in UEFI mode. Good backups needed.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. Strangely enough, booting into Windows started working again without any intervention...