# Partition issues after installing Ubuntu 22.04 with Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, ssd

I have a Yoga720-15IKB laptop running Windows 10. I wanted to dual boot Ubuntu 22.04 and Windows, so I shrank my C: drive (the only main partition at the moment) on the only drive (an SSD) in the laptop, and created 2 more partitions using the free space. One was for installing Ubuntu and the other was like a shared space for storage for both operating systems.

During the Ubuntu installation, I selected *Something else*, and reformatted the partition I wanted to install to, then installed Ubuntu to that partition. Now I could boot into both Windows and Ubuntu without any issue, but the partitions were not right.

Windows Disk Management:

[image: Windows Disk Management]

It only shows my C: drive but with a red cross, and it doesn't show any other partition info and I can't do any disk operation here. (There shouldn't be an issue with Windows Disk Management because it can show any external drive correctly).

Then I tried to fix this with a Windows recovery USB drive. I loaded the recovery environment and tried `diskpart`. When I ran `list disk` I saw this:

[image: list disk photo]

It only showed my USB drive as disk 1, but can't see my internal SSD (normally disk 0). Then I tried `sel disk 0` anyway and it was still able to select my SSD somehow. Then I did `list partition` and I saw this.

[image: list partition photo]

This time it seems to be showing the partitions correctly unless I missed something, but I still don't know how to fix it or even what caused this. I think I also tried the auto "Startup Repair" and the `fixmbr` command in the recovery environment, but I had no luck.

I even tried to reinstall Windows, but during the installation when I needed to select the drive/partition to install Windows, the installer couldn't find any drive, like this.

[image: Windows installer photo]

Does anyone know what this issue is and how to fix it? It would be better if I can fix it without reinstalling either operating system or even reformatting.

Comment: You created dynamic partitions which is proprietary to Windows & has no undo with Windows. Some third party Windows tools may work. https://askubuntu.com/questions/482768/changing-windows-dynamic-disk-partition-to-basic-partition-and-not-the-full-driv  & https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2325331&p=13492758&viewfull=1#post13492758  If you have Windows 10 in UEFI with gpt, you do not even need dynamic partiitons. It was another work around for the 4 primary partition limit in MBR(msdos).

Comment: @guiverc, sorry, I thought it was just a minor version number. It's 22.04, I edited the question.

Comment: @oldfred, thanks, I will try that later.

Comment: @oldfred, sharing my updates. I ended up using the free version of the AOMEI Partition Assistant to convert my dynamic partitions to basic partitions. After the conversion, I couldn't boot into any system. Maybe it's because the boot table was destroyed, either by the ubuntu installation or by the AOMEI Partition Assistant. Anyway, I tried the auto "Startup Repair" and the `fixmbr` command in the recovery environment again, no luck. But this time, the windows installer was able to recognize the partitions. So, I did a clean Windows install then reinstalled Ubuntu. Now everything's working.