Partition in Linux Does Not Appear in Windows
I have a problem regarding dual-boot installation of Ubuntu. I'm not very familiar on dual-booting but I follow several turtorial to do it. During installation of Ubuntu as dual-boot, I did not choose the option of manually partition, instead i choose the automatically partition and resize it to match the amount of unallocated storage. After installation, it works perfectly fine for both windows and ubuntu. However I found that my Ubuntu and several partition is not detected in Disk Management.
The steps for installation:

Shrink local disk E: (HDD) for unallocated space
Bitlocker is disabled
Disabled secure boot and fast startup
Boot from UEFI USB Ubuntu
Install alongside Windows Boot Manager
Partition: choose the default installation instead of manually partition (Using manual partition did not detect unallocated space)

I have 2 storage, SSD (Windows) and HDD (Several Windows programs and data). The HDD storage has several partition;

Local Disk D: 510.82 GB for some applications
Local Disk E: 225.37 GB for data
Unallocated: ~195 GB

Even though it works perfectly fine, I'm afraid it will cause issues in the near future, and i want my linux partition and windows data partition to be shown in disk management. Can you please help me on this issue.
My idea:
my current solution is probably to delete volume for Local Disk D and E to delete Ubuntu and delete several data I have in windows to reinstall ubuntu back using manually partition. However a second opinion or more can be my consideration to not delete my file in windows.
Thank you for your attention
Disk Management

This is expected. Windows cannot see ext4 drives. If you want to resize partitions then boot a Ubuntu live image and use GParted to resize partitions.

Not sure why Windows would create dynaptic partitions, anymore. That was one of the work arounds for very old MBR 4 primary partition limit. With gpt that limit is gone. You need to undo the dynamic partitions in Windows. https://askubuntu.com/questions/482768/changing-windows-dynamic-disk-partition-to-basic-partition-and-not-the-full-driv & https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2325331&p=13492758&viewfull=1#post13492758 & https://www.partitionwizard.com/partitionmanager/convert-dynamic-disk-to-basic.html Be sure to have good backups.

"I found that my Ubuntu and several partition is not detected in [Windows] Disk Management."
There is nothing wrong with your system.
This is normal Windows Disk Management behavior.
Feel free to file a bug report with Microsoft.

First, the Windows OS doesn't recognize the ext4 partitions that Linux uses, so they won't be shown.
If you want to be able to share data between Window and Ubuntu. There is a tool called Gparted that is for adjusting partitions, you may need to install it with apt install gparted.
Using Gparted, you can create a ntfs partition that both Windows and Ubuntu can access to store shared data.  There is already lots of documentation on how to perform that task.
Important: Before you begin to adjust the partitions with Gparted, make a complete backup of both your Windows and Ubuntu OS.
