Delete EFI system partition on Windows 10
I needed Ubuntu 22.04 for my internship, also I wanted to try Arch in my free time, so I did Dual(Triple) Boot with GRUB, where I could choose Windows, Ubuntu or Arch. Now I dont need it anymore, so I deleted both Ubuntu and Arch partitions in Windows 10, using Disk Management. However, the 143mb EFI system partition cannot be deleted using Disk Management. Also, when I restart my laptop, GRUB command line shows, where I type exit and load from bios. Additionally, I accidentally converted my HDD to dynamic disk, it was basic.
I tried removing it with diskpart, didnt work. EaseUS also cant delete it, neither convert the disk back to basic from dynamic.
How do I remove the EFI System Partition and boot my laptop with windows without typing anything again?This is the current state my disks in Disk Management

You have to have an ESP - efi system partition to boot in UEFI mode. And dynamic partitions are not required, but Microsoft makes it easy to convert to dynamic but not back to basic. Some Windows tools do not work with dynamic. Best to convert back, but need third party tools.https://askubuntu.com/questions/482768/changing-windows-dynamic-disk-partition-to-basic-partition-and-not-the-full-driv &

This question is similar to: How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
